# IP restriction not working when following documentation of Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, ip-restrictions

I want to try to restrict access to a webrole based on 'Cloud Services' based on IP. There is a good documentation in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windowsazure/jj154098.aspx), but when I follow it I get an error when deploying it.

The error I get is:
`Recycling (Role has encountered an error and has stopped. Application startup task failed with exit code 1`

It is getting wrong on the part of

`%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity`

So I think the command is wrong, I am running the *Webrole* on Operating System Windows 2012.

When only adding the *web.config* part nothing changes and it does not work

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <!—Unlisted IP addresses are denied access–>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted=”false”>
        <!—The following IP addresses are granted access–>
            <add allowed=”true” ipAddress=”192.168.100.1” subnetMask=”255.255.0.0″ />
           <add allowed=”true” ipAddress=”192.168.100.2″ subnetMask=”255.255.0.0″ />
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Is there anybody with experience with this, who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log in to any running instance of a windows azure cloud service via RDP and start up a command line with elevated privileges you can test such commands before using them in a startup script. That way you might get a proper error message.

I tried it on one of my Azure instances and I noticed:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe unlock config - section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity
```

never exits but

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe unlock config /section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity
```

does the trick.

Comment: Nico, thanks for your reply. You are correct it with the command. But there is some more to get this working. You also have to install the feature IP Address and Domain Restrictions in IIS. Then you can set the restriction according to the documentation of Microsoft posted in my question.

Comment: install the feature IP Address and Domain Restrictions in IIS with a startup command >>> PowerShell Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-IP-Security